# Microsoft Graph Api / Teams - Unable to list chat messages in a channel (401 / 403)

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to list message in a channel in Teams using Graph Api, and I get a 401 (Unknown Error) response from the server.
Listing teams and listing channels in teams works. Getting the channel also works, but I can't get messages.
I'm using App ID (deamon scenario) and the nodejs graph api.

If anyone can point me in the right direction...

(edit, more info)

```
const client = GraphClient.initWithMiddleware({
  defaultVersion: 'beta',
  authProvider: new AuthProvider()
});

await client
  .api(`/teams/${teamid}/channels/${channelid}/messages`)
  .get();
```

and the app permissions:
[image: app permission]

(edit 2, decoded jwt token)
[image: jwt token]

Comment: 401 usually means unauthorized. There should be something wrong with your access token. Could you please share more details? Any code? Are you referring to any sample?

Comment: thanks @AllenWu, I've added my api call (really simple) as well as the app permission as the error code would imply it comes from there.

Comment: The permissions look good. Could you share me with the code about the "client"?

Comment: @Nico Could you please check your access token with [jwt](https://jwt.io) and see if it has all the [required permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions)?

Comment: thanks @Gousia-MSFT. I've pasted the decoded token which seems to have what it needs.

Comment: @AllenWu I've updated code with client creation. AuthProvider is just a dead simple class that return a token I got from login.microsoftonline.com (and which works for other calls).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't change anything but I'm now getting a 403 instead of a 401. Still only on /messages, getting channel info works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is apparently not supported as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis.

Extract from the documentation:

*Microsoft Teams APIs in Microsoft Graph that access sensitive data are considered protected APIs. These APIs require that you have additional validation, beyond permissions and consent, before you can use them.
The following APIs are currently protected:*

- *List channel messages using application permissions*
- *Get channel message using application permissions*
- *List replies to a message using application permissions*
- *Get a reply to a message using application permissions*
- *List messages in a chat using application permissions*
- *Get message in chat using application permissions*

There is a manual process to ask those permission to Microsoft. See the documentation.

Comment: That link seems to indicate it's not supported with **Application** permissions, but even with **Delegated** permissions we are getting a 403 Forbidden. <br/>Does anyone have a definitive answer on what permissions are needed to access https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/messages?<br/>It seems incredibly restrictive to require the caller to be a member\owner of the team in order to access its messages. No other graph API is so restrictive as far as I know.

Comment: From what I understand it's either application with a derogation from Microsoft or delgated but then you'll have to be part of the teams.